# increasing object allocations in instruments

Tags: ios4, ios-simulator

**Hi friends My App is retrieving Data from SQLServer through web service,and storing into Local SQLite Database,and Displays Data in Table View while i am running App through instruments its showing Fallowing Allocations...
Can Any one Help why these objects are still in memory....?**

[image]
[image]

Comment: Why do you want to store that in database,if you can directly display from webservices.

Answer (score 0):

Show us the code that you're using when inserting/updating records. Most probably you're allocating an object which you are then not releasing. For example:

```
NSString *someString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Yo"];
[myDictionary setValue:someString forKey:@"stringValue"];
```

You need to then call [someString release] to release the allocated object. Go over the code and see if you're 'alloc'ing something which you are then not releasing.